# Suse 10.3 won't do anything after openssl upgrade. /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found

Tags: linux, glibc, opensuse

I upgraded my openssl version with the command:

```
rpm -i --nodeps openssl-0.9.8p-1.x86_64.rpm
```

And now I get following error for almost every command I enter:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
```

Will a simple update of GLIBC be enough? Like

```
rpm -i --nodeps glibc-2.9-2.9.x86_64.rpm
```

I'm kind of scared to try that because of the damage i've already caused.

Comment: Please help me...i'm on a customer system and am freaking out. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, well, requiring --nodeps should be a big flashing sign that you're about to shoot yourself in the foot. Replacing core packages with some random rpm from the internet is unlikely to be successful, as you've noticed. Better luck next time, dude.

FWIW, you might be able to install the original openssl rpm by booting from a CD and playing with chroot.

Or, since Suse 10.3 isn't supported anymore anyway, you might as well update the entire system while you're at it.

Comment: yeah thats what i turned out doing. thanks for the heads-up.